# spark scala split timestamp column in date column and time column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with split of a timestamp column into Date and time columns. 
First the time doesn't consider 24h format ... 
Second the date is false and i don't understand why

here is my output

```
+----------+----------+-------------------+---------+
|      Date| Timestamp|               Time|EventTime|
+----------+----------+-------------------+---------+
|2018-00-30|1540857600|2018-10-30 00:00:00| 12:00:00|
|2018-00-30|1540857610|2018-10-30 00:00:10| 12:00:10|
|2018-00-30|1540857620|2018-10-30 00:00:20| 12:00:20|
|2018-00-30|1540857630|2018-10-30 00:00:30| 12:00:30|
|2018-00-30|1540857640|2018-10-30 00:00:40| 12:00:40|
|2018-00-30|1540857650|2018-10-30 00:00:50| 12:00:50|
|2018-01-30|1540857660|2018-10-30 00:01:00| 12:01:00|
|2018-01-30|1540857670|2018-10-30 00:01:10| 12:01:10|
|2018-01-30|1540857680|2018-10-30 00:01:20| 12:01:20|
|2018-01-30|1540857690|2018-10-30 00:01:30| 12:01:30|
|2018-01-30|1540857700|2018-10-30 00:01:40| 12:01:40|
```

and my code :

```
  val df = data_input
    .withColumn("Time", to_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("Timestamp"))))
    .withColumn("Date", date_format(col("Time"), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
    .withColumn("EventTime", date_format(col("Time"), "hh:mm:ss"))
```

first I convert the unix Timestamp column to Time column, and then i want to split Time..

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong format codes.  Specifically "mm" in your date is for minutes, and "hh" is for 12 hour values.  Instead you want "MM" and "HH".  Like this:

```
val df = data_input
    .withColumn("Time", to_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("Timestamp"))))
    .withColumn("Date", date_format(col("Time"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
    .withColumn("EventTime", date_format(col("Time"), "HH:mm:ss"))
```

For reference, here are the date format codes that you can use: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the confusion with simple casting

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = data_input
    .withColumn("Time", $"Timestamp".cast("timestamp"))
    .withColumn("Date", $"Time".cast("date"))
    .withColumn("EventTime", date_format($"Time", "H:m:s"))

+----------+-------------------+----------+---------+
|Timestamp |               Time|      Date|EventTime|
+----------+-------------------+----------+---------+
|1540857600|2018-10-30 00:00:00|2018-10-30|    0:0:0|
|1540857610|2018-10-30 00:00:10|2018-10-30|   0:0:10|
|1540857620|2018-10-30 00:00:20|2018-10-30|   0:0:20|
|1540857630|2018-10-30 00:00:30|2018-10-30|   0:0:30|
|1540857640|2018-10-30 00:00:40|2018-10-30|   0:0:40|
|1540857650|2018-10-30 00:00:50|2018-10-30|   0:0:50|
|1540857660|2018-10-30 00:01:00|2018-10-30|    0:1:0|
|1540857670|2018-10-30 00:01:10|2018-10-30|   0:1:10|
|1540857680|2018-10-30 00:01:20|2018-10-30|   0:1:20|
|1540857690|2018-10-30 00:01:30|2018-10-30|   0:1:30|
|1540857700|2018-10-30 00:01:40|2018-10-30|   0:1:40|
+----------+-------------------+----------+---------+
```